# Redux syntax for reducers in react.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

just trying to clear up a syntax issue, whether or not the following code will output the same result. One is an ES7 snippet using rxreducer , so it would be a lot easier to use:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  currentUser: null,
};

const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_CURRENT_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

or this is the code given using an ES7 snippet with values added in:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  currentUser: null,
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "SET_CURRENT_USER":
      return { ...state, 
        currentUser: payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: It will be the same. Just try to run it to make sure of it.

Comment: just make sure you use : const useReducer = ()  instead of export default, just 
export default useReducer at the bottom